# Why isn't Phineas appearing in my town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When you reach milestones, e.g. 50% of insect types caught, Phineas is supposed to appear to hand you a badge.

I've received the bronze one for Deep Sea Creatures, but haven't seen him since, despite having 60% of insects.

Does he only come once a week or something?  Why haven't I received the bronze insect-catching badge as yet?

Comment: I think he's a random encounter like Saharah, Katrina etc. Not sure if there are different conditions for him though.

Comment: The problem I've had is that Copper tells me he's there, but I just can't find him at all, which has happened on 2 days now. It's quite frustrating.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding Phineas on days that he actually is in your town, consider buying a Megaphone from the Nookling's store (1+ Upgrades) and using that to locate Phineas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is a random encounter. He also will not appear when it is raining. I know a lot of players have had an extremely rainy June. This may be a factor. :)

> [[Phineas] can be found in the city at anytime of the day in reasonable weather conditions (sunny or overcast/cloudy)](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Phineas)

Comment: Is there any reference for this or is this your personal experience?

Comment: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Phineas  personal experience as well. :3

Comment: I see. You should put such informations in answers, it's improving its credibility a lot. Anyway, welcome to the ArQAde, here's your first [upvote](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) :-)

Comment: Thank you kindly! I'm new, so I really appreciate the tip!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, have a look at the [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) site, there's a brief overview about voting etc. And you get a shiny badge as well ;-)

Comment: In fact I noticed two of your other posts seem worth upvoting, so now you [can upvote](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)